# How to get the controls list which are initialized in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a winforms project, how can I get the list of controls which are initialized in designer only and not from form and somewhere else.

Or can I know if the control has some designer instance.

Comment: It would be good if you can share why you would want to do this? Will you be treating the design time initialised controls different ? What different treatment you will have for them?

Comment: Hi @ChetanRanpariya, i have a project where i add controls in runtime with a button click, even i have an option to reset and add again the controls which were added before in run time. so it would be helpful what are all controls added at starting in designer.

Comment: By the time the method `InitializeComponent()` is called in the constructor, you can get the list of designer-generated controls by enumerating the `ControlCollection` of the form: `foreach (Control c in this.Controls)`, if this is what you want.

Comment: Hi @kennyzx, i dont need the controls list in Form.cs i need it in different class. If i follow your approach in a diff class i think i will get all the controls which were added in designer and form

Comment: @nikhilesholety My suggestion would be to create a list of controls which you are generating at run time and deal with it. it would be easier than to worry about the design time generated controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give those initialized in designer a special tag to separate them from those are added later in code.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        control.Tag = "FromDesigner";
    }
}
```

Then in the other class

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
foreach (Control c in form1.Controls)
{
    if (c.Tag != null && c.Tag.Equals("FromDesigner"))
    {
    }
}
```